# How to get the last inserted whole row in mysql in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqljs

How can I get the whole just inserted data without another query, is that possible?

I know the ID is there in the response payload: data.insertId

My issue is that when I insert the values there is an auto timestamp and I need it, but I don't want to query the DB again because of performance

```
db.query(`INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(prd_name, prd_price) \
  VALUES('${this.prd_name}',${this.prd_price})`, (err, data) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Product added.',
    newProductData: data.WHOLE_ROW?????,
  });
});
```

Comment: Bad news for you: you have to query the database again. But I would not fret over an extra query, that's what databases are designed for.

Comment: @Shadow: ok!...

Comment: Of course, if you generated your auto timestamp in your application code, then you would know it beforehand

Comment: You might also consider adding Knex which offers many convenience methods. In your case the `.returning()` function would be handy. [http://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning]